# How to make tabs scrollable in compose

Tags: android, kotlin, tabs, android-jetpack-compose

I want to add dynamic tab items. in a scrollable way, not fixed tabs

I followed this example [here](https://johncodeos.com/how-to-create-tabs-with-jetpack-compose/)

But after I implement the same, still the tabs fixed, what I want is to show the whote text of the tab (Not fixed size tab), and the tabs must be scrollable like the following image

[image]

I tried to make the TabRaw scrollable as the following:

```
 TabRow(
    selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
    backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(MaterialTheme.spacing._20sdp)
        .horizontalScroll(scrollableState)
        .height(32.dp),
    contentColor = colorResource(id = R.color.primary)
)
```

But it throws IllegalArgumentException, Because I'm including it in a ConstraintLayout

Comment: Instead of TabRow you can directly use ScrollableTabRow composable. Refer the documentation here - https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I only used ScrollableTabRow instead of TabRow

Comment: That's it. The answer I'm looking for is concise. Thanks bro :)

Comment: ScrollableTabRow shrinks the width of Tab. How to make Tab's width fit to ScrollableTabRow?